# Tag description cutting off at the wrong word - is it better to just show directly?

Tags: bug, design, tag-wiki-excerpt

When I searched on SO for the `postgresql` tag, I got the following description below the tag:

> PostgreSQL is an open-source, object-relational database management
>   system (ORDBMS) available for all major platforms including Linux,
>   UNIX, Windows and OS X. Please mention your exact version of Postgres
>   when asking questions. Questions concerning administration or advanced
>   features are best ...

This struck me as odd, so I went to the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info):

> PostgreSQL is an open-source, object-relational database management
>   system (ORDBMS) available for all major platforms including Linux,
>   UNIX, Windows and OS X. Please mention your exact version of Postgres
>   when asking questions. Questions concerning administration or advanced
>   features are best directed to dba.stackexchange.com.

Needless to say, the mini-description was copied from here by some piece of code, and it just mindlessly cut off at precisely the wrong word.

Could something be done about this? Maybe making tag descriptions editable or shorter(so it won't truncate) or displaying the entire contents without cutting off anything?

Comment: They are editable... submit an edit suggestion.

Comment: @Catija I didn't know that. Thanks.
Edit: I just tried, and it's going to edit the main tag wiki. Would it be possible to just edit the short description?

Comment: Yes. There's two sections. The main tag wiki and the tag wiki excerpt. You want the excerpt.